# Push notification for android stays always at bottom

Tags: push-notification, android-push-notification

The push notification for my app always stays at the bottom of the notification tray screen no matter when it is sent. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Is there something that I can do so that the app's push notifications come to top of the notification tray when a device receives it?

Comment: Previously I did not put sound parameter in payload.`sound:"default"`
Now the notifications seems to appear at top for Android. How does this change effect the position of the notification in the notification-tray?